# Bash how to parse asscoiative array from argument?

Tags: bash, associative-array

I am trying to read a string into an associative array.

The string is being properly escaped and read into .sh file:

```
./myScript.sh "[\"el1\"]=\"val1\" [\"el2\"]=\"val2\""
```

within the script

```
#!/bin/bash -e
declare -A myArr=( "${1}" ) #it doesn't work either with or without quotes
```

All I get is:

```
line 2: myArr: "${1}": must use subscript when assigning associative array
```

Googling the error only results in "your array is not properly formatted" results.

Comment: Please try: `declare -A "myArr=( ${1} )"`

Comment: Like using `eval` this is likely to produce code injection or other bugs when dealing with complex inputs.

Comment: Would you be OK with something like `./myScript.sh el1 val1 el2 val2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
./test.sh "( [\"el1\"]=\"val1\" [\"el2\"]=\"val2\" )"
```

and within the script:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

declare -A myArr="${1}"
declare -p myArr

for i in "${!myArr[@]}"
do
  echo "key  : $i"
  echo "value: ${myArr[$i]}"
done
```

Returns:

```
> ./test.sh "( [\"el1\"]=\"val1\" [\"el2\"]=\"val2\" )"
declare -A myArr=([el2]="val2" [el1]="val1" )
key  : el2
value: val2
key  : el1
value: val1
```

I can't explain why this works, or why the order changes though.

[Test it yourself here](https://onlinegdb.com/BkqxdGI7_)

Comment: This doesn't work in my testing; it creates a single array element (indexed by "0") containing the entire argument as a literal string. Add `declare -p myArr` at the end to see what's actually happening.

Comment: @GordonDavisson it works for me perfectly - what is your issue? also improved on answer, you can see the output of  `declare -p myArr`

Comment: Ah, I see, I was testing it without supplying the outer parentheses in the argument (I just copied the argument format from the original question). With parens, it works for me too.

Answer (score 3):

You could read key/value pairs from variable inputs in series:

```
$ cat > example.bash <<'EOF'
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A key_values
while true
do
    key_values+=(["$1"]="$2")
    shift 2
    if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
    then
        break
    fi
done

for key in "${!key_values[@]}"
do
    echo "${key} = ${key_values[$key]}"
done
EOF
$ chmod u+x example.bash
$ ./example.bash el1 val1 el2 val2
el2 = val2
el1 = val1
```

This should be safe no matter what the keys and values are.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of caring about proper double escaping, set the variables on caller side, and use bash `declare -p`. That way you will always get properly escaped string.

```
declare -A temp=([el1]=val1 [el2]=val2)
./script.sh "$(declare -p temp)"
```

Then do:

```
# ./script.sh
# a safer version of `eval "$1"`
declare -A myarr="${1#*=}"
```